# truncate a decimal number to nearest 4 decimals and assert

Tags: c++

How is it possible to round off a floating point number with 4 decimal points and use it in assert. I am calculating the mean of a sample by two methods, and want to compare them through assert. Because of the difference in the mean in the 6th decimal point ( which is OK ), I get an assertion error.

Is it possible to truncate the last 2 decimal points or rather possible to acccept only the first 4 decimal points.

most of the commands such as `std::precision` is for input output operation as I have seen. What is the signifigance of `std::numeric_limits`?

I have a workaround, when I multiply the floating point number with 10000 and floor the number. That works, but a proper solution would be helpful.

```
float  mean, mean_x;
mean = 1.123456;
mean_x = 1.123499;
assert(std::floor(mean*10000) == std::floor(mean_x*10000));
```

Comment: being lazy, I would simply convert `float` into `std::string` and manually cut down to `n` significant digits, but it won't be very efficient. Yours is probably better atm

Comment: You can subtract the numbers and verify that the difference is small enough.

Comment: @BoPersson 's suggestion can be implemented with `std::abs(mean - mean_x)<1e-4` ([`abs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/) from `cmath`)

Answer (score 3):

You can NOT round `float` to particular precision as amount of decimal digits, as internally the float value is ∑ (b<sub>i</sub>/2<sup>i</sup>) values with *i* being 1..24 for `float` (when the platform does use IEEE 754 standard floating point implementation). So for example 1/1024 = 0.0009765625 => you may need this one to adjust the fourth decimal digit by cca. +-9, but it will also add few more decimal digits after the fourth.

That's why the OUTPUT is formatted (rounded) to particular amount of decimal digits, but value is kept intact.

In unit testing there's usually special assert dedicated to floating values comparison, which has further argument *epsilon*, specifying the maximal value difference to be tolerated (in your case 1e-4 would do).

If you don't use some unit testing framework with extensive asserts, you may use Steve's suggestion (which is implementation of such floating assert):

```
// assert that the difference is smaller than 0.0001
assert(std::abs(mean - mean_x) < 1e-4);  // (abs from cmath)
```

---

related docs about how `float` works (on most of the platforms):
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Eh, this argument is flawed, but it's a second-order error about second-order errors ;). In cases like this, it's OK to check if the relative difference is less than 0.000099999784 instead of less than 0.0001.